# How to load different image with smooth transition using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my layout :

[image]

- My goal is to load a diff image when I click on a btn `View All Students`.
- Ratherthan, flashing to a new image right the way, I want it to have a smooth transition.
  when I change the `src` attribute.
- I tried using `$('img #bot-image-path ').slideDown(1000);`, but that doesn't seem to take any effect.

How would I achieve something like that in jQuery ?

Here is my live Result : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/ry5jLcmm/5/)

Comment: Are you wanting to slide up an image, replace it's source and then slide it down with the new image?

Comment: have you tried using fadeIn() instead of slideDown()??

Comment: See my answer using fadeIn and fadeOut

Comment: @tic I've seen your answer already. thats just a simple fadeIn() fadeOut() example. I am referring to his fiddle where most of the code is missing and confusing.

Comment: @Sushil  I agree, the code posted is not clear. I was just posting a simple example that could hopefully be modified for the OP's use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using something like the following?

```
[selector].show( speed, [callback] );
```

This will fade in the image over 'speed' ms. Callback isnt necessary. You can read more about it here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-effects.htm.

Edit: Also, removing the 'img' in front of the actual div id might help!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I tried using $('img #bot-image-path ').slideDown(1000);, but that doesn't seem to take any effect.
> ```

`$('img #bot-image-path ')` Will select a div with id `#bot-image-path` inside of any image in your window, which would be invalid html. You likely just mean `$('#bot-image-path')`

Instead of sliding...You can do a fade of 2 images asynchronously, with a simple example (Click the cats):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tic84/tLe6g9q7/)